# How to use two different params hashes in one page (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi
I want to use two params hashes in one page

The job of this page is straightforward, it's an edit page, and I want it to send out notifications to a server once the editing job is done.

```
def update
      @description = Tempdescription.find(params[:id])
     @description.update_attributes(params[:tempdescription])
      sendnotification     
end 

def sendnotification
       params[:to_ids]="xxxx"
       sig = hash_params(params);
       params[:sig] = sig 
     response = RestClient.post "http://api.xxxx.com/restserver.do",  params, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
       render :text=>response
end

def hash_params(params)
      params = Hash[*params.sort.flatten]
    payload = ''
    params.sort.each do |pair|
         key, value = pair
     payload = payload + "#{key}=#{value}"
    end
    return Digest::MD5.hexdigest(payload + API_SECRET)
 end
```

Not surprisingly the params in sendnotification also includes params used for updating

and the server returns 104 error

Therefore,
I tried

```
new_params=Hash[]
```

and use new_params to replace the old params in sendnotification

But then rails complains

```
 undefined method `<=>' for :session_key:Symbol
 app/controllers/tempdescriptions_controller.rb:72:in `<=>'
  app/controllers/tempdescriptions_controller.rb:72:in `sort'
  app/controllers/tempdescriptions_controller.rb:72:in `hash_params'
  app/controllers/tempdescriptions_controller.rb:45:in `sendnotification'
```

So I am thinking if there is any way I can create another params?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing so many things wrong, it's hard to know where to start :(

Comment: So, what's your solution ;) I think it's known that something is wrong.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to read your code if you removed the tabs, or at least used them consistently. The universally accepted convention in ruby is to indent with two spaces. Also, your use of space between operators is a mess.

Comment: well I use the similar ways to call other RESTFUL API methods (like get user info) and they worked.

Comment: Indentation changes somehow when I copy and paste my code.

Comment: It is interesting that most people replied here didn't deal with the problems directly and criticized something trivial instead.

Comment: @noodl I use other people's hash_params(params) method directly.

Comment: @Andy - why don't you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @JayX - it's interesting that your ego is this big. This site is not meant for throwing up code and asking why it doesn't work... It's meant to get help from experienced coders when all else has failed. You haven't even isolated to a single line. Read the error message, trace the stack, fiddle - it's error debugging 101. It's not our JOB to answer your question and if you get sassy about it, you'll never get an answer.

Comment: @seth.vargo If I didn't elaborate well, then I am sorry, but I did find the problem and I am looking for help, and my purpose is quite clear, I want to use two params hashes in one page (it is my title), that is it. I am sorry but I am confused by what you just posted here.

Comment: @JayX - "well I use the similar ways to call other RESTFUL API methods (like get user info) and they worked" and "It is interesting that most people replied here didn't deal with the problems directly and criticized something trivial instead". Furthermore, you clearly don't understand Rails enough to know that the params hash is a HASH. you can make another freaking hash with Hash.new and throw stuff into it. Params is just special because its automatically passed with each request, but you can also manually pass any hash and rails will behave the same way

Comment: @seth.vargo I am sowie, but clearly you simply skimmed through my question and couldn't wait to criticize me, did you see I tried new_params=Hash[] but failed? Anyway, so far you are the only one who really answers my question, thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay... again... clearly you dont know ruby... thats not how you make a hash. Hash.new or {} (empty curly braces) make a new hash

Comment: @seth.vargo I tried Hash[] Hash.new and {} in my rails console and they all returned the same result {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, having complained about your formatting I suppose I should hazard an attempt at your problem.

This code:

```
def hash_params(params)
  params = Hash[*params.sort.flatten]
  payload = ''
  params.sort.each do |pair|
    key, value = pair
    payload = payload + "#{key}=#{value}"
  end
  return Digest::MD5.hexdigest(payload + API_SECRET)
end
```

.. appears to accept a hash as its argument and then recreate it with the keys sorted. Presumably this code is targeted at ruby 1.9 otherwise that would be rather pointless. It then sorts *again* for no reason I can determine before joining the keys and values with `=` but without separating the pairs with `&`.

The error is a little mysterious though; I have no trouble sorting symbols with ruby 1.9. Perhaps you're running ruby 1.8?

Comment: Yes I am running 1.8 and I think I solve the problem myself, although I still don't understand why...thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...after playing with rails console for a while I finally find a solution to this problem.

In sendnotification method I created a new hash

```
    p=Hash[]
```

but simply putting this will not work, as I mentioned before.
Then I changed all 
      p[:key]
    to
      p["key"]
and it works.

Obviously Hash#sort doesn't work with hash[:key] if the hash is newly created but it works with params and that's what puzzled me and made me believe there is a difference between params and normal hash.

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 so I think it might just be a bug of this version.

Comment: It's not a bug, it just that in 1.8 Symbol#:<=> isn't defined so you can't sort an array for symbols (for example). You could easily fix that by stringifying them or by using `sort_by` rather than `sort` but I honestly think that `.sort` call is redundant anyway. Also, `Hash[]` is pointlessly long and is exactly equivalent to the shorter hash literal `{}`.